# Escape special character in ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm working on a playbook to modify a sql script, I need to create a string with a concatenation of conditionals.
this is the conditional structure:

```
(server.primary_name||'.'||server.arpa_domain like '%server_name%')
```

This is the ansible task:

```
- name: Query Conditionals
  set_fact:
    query_conditionals_list: "{{ query_conditionals_list + [ '(server.primary_name||.||server.arpa_domain like %' + item + '%)' ] }}"
  with_items: "{{ server_names }}"
  when: "item not in query_conditionals"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{item}}"

- name: Join names
  set_fact:
    query_conditionals: "{{query_conditionals_list | join (' OR ')}}"
```

I believe that I'm not escaping correctly the parentesis and the single qoutes.
Is it possible to escape them?

Thanks

**EDIT**
I made some modifications.
As suggested by mdaniel, instead of creating the string from the get go, I'm creating first a list and then doing a join with the OR. So that solves my OR problem.
Although, I was not able to escape the single quotes yet

Comment: [`query_conditionals: >-` yaml scalar folding](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2779048) to free up `"` for use as a string literal, and then using [`join(" OR ")`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#join) are the things you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround using vars on the ansible task.
While using vars, I was able to maintain the structure I wanted to use and save the single quotes.

```
- name: Query Conditionals
  set_fact:
    query_conditionals_list: "{{ query_conditionals_list + [ server_item ] }}"
  when: "item not in query_conditionals_list"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{item}}"
  vars: 
    server_item: "(server.primary_name||'.'||server.arpa_domain like '%{{item}}%')"
  with_items: "{{ server_names }}"
```